# Django ModelViewSet or GenericView which one is better in term of db query?

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, query-optimization

I have an order model with multiple ForeignKey and ManyToMany Fields. For CRUD operation I used ModelViewSet.

But when I analyse db query of order list or retrieve APIs, I found it consumes more db query then a GenericView with same functionality. ModelViewSet takes 30+ query for order list where generic API with same functionality only takes 10+ query.

But can't understand why! I noticed modelviewset fetch all related field (foreign key and many-to-many) separately, where I can use select_related + prefetch_related for query optimization.

Here is my code, please let me know if anyone figure out same issue, thanks!

```
#ORDER_MODEL

class Order(models.Model):
    customer= models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name= 'orders', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
....
    delivery_method= models.ForeignKey(DeliveryMethod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='orders', null=True)
    address= models.ForeignKey(CustomerAddress, related_name='order_address', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    status = models.ForeignKey(OrderStatus, related_name='orders', on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null= True)
```

```
#ORDER_MODEL_VIEW_SET

class OrderViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Order.objects.select_related(
        'customer', 'status', 'coupon', 'delivery_method', 'address'
    ).prefetch_related('order_products').order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = OrderSerializerDashboard
    pagination_class = CommonPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = OrderFilter
```

```
#ORDER_GENERIC_VIEW

class OrderListView(GenericAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    queryset = Order.objects.select_related(
        'customer', 'status', 'coupon', 'delivery_method', 'address', 'address__area', \
        'address__area__district'
    ).prefetch_related('order_products').order_by('-id')
    pagination_class = CommonPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_class = OrderFilter

    def get(self, request, id=None):
        purpose = request.query_params.get('purpose')

        if purpose == 'get_select_options':
            data = {}
            data['status_options'] = OrderStatus.objects.values('id', 'name', 'order')
            data['customer_options'] = Customer.objects.values('id', 'name')
            data['payment_method_options'] = PAYMENT_METHOD
            data['delivery_method'] = DeliveryMethod.objects.values('id', 'name')
            data['payment_status_options'] = ONLINE_PAYMENT_STATUS
            single_data_obj = SingleData.objects.first()
            data['default_delivery_person_number'] = single_data_obj.\
                delivery_person_number if single_data_obj else ''
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        elif id != None:
            order_object = self.queryset.filter(id=id).first()
            if not order_object:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
            serializer = OrderSerializerDashboard(
                order_object, context={'purpose': 'order_details'}
            )
            data = {}
            data['order_details'] = serializer.data
            data['payment_status_options'] = ONLINE_PAYMENT_STATUS
            data['payment_method_options'] = PAYMENT_METHOD
            return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        elif purpose == 'order_list_page':
            queryset = self.queryset.filter(status_id__in=[1,2,4,5])

        elif purpose == 'fulfillment_list_page':
            queryset = self.queryset.filter(status_id__in=[3,6,7])

        filter_queryset = self.filter_queryset(queryset)
        paginate_queryset = self.paginate_queryset(filter_queryset)
        serializer = OrderSerializerDashboard(paginate_queryset, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Please wrap all of your code blocks in ``` ``` to have them render as code.